# StackOverflowError in a terminating loop?

Tags: java, regex, loops, overflow

To give some context: I recently started playing Dungeons and Dragons with a group of friends. I decided I wanted to try to make a program that allowed me to search for spells by level, school of magic, etc. To do this, I took a text file with every spell and its information listed alphabetically by spell name, and created a few regex expressions to sort through it all. I finally got it to give me the correct results for every attribute. But once I put it in a loop to get everything at once, I get a long list of errors, beginning with StackOverflowError. As far as I'm aware, this is supposed to happen when you get infinite loops, but mine definitely terminates. Moreover, I can go farther looping manually (with a loop that checks a boolean that I set with the keyboard at the end of each loop) than I can with a simple for or while loop.

The code I'm using is below. I didn't include the Spell class because it's just standard getters/setters and variable declarations. The School type I have is just an enum with the eight schools.

```
Map<String, Spell> allSpells = new HashMap<String, Spell>();
    ArrayList<Spell> spellArray = new ArrayList<Spell>();

    int finalLevel;
    int lastMatch = 0;
    int startIndex = 0;
    Matcher match;
    String finalTitle;
    Spell.School finalSchool;
    String finalDescription;
    String fullList;

    
    String titleString = ".+:\\n";                                          //Finds the titles of spells
    Pattern titlePattern = Pattern.compile(titleString);
    String levelString = "\\d\\w+-level";                                   //Finds the level of spells
    Pattern levelPattern = Pattern.compile(levelString);
    String schoolString = "(C|c)onjuration|(A|a)bjuration|(E|e)nchantment|(N|n)ecromancy|(E|e)vocation|(D|d)ivination|(I|i)llusion|(T|t)ransmutation";  //Finds the school of spells
    Pattern schoolPattern = Pattern.compile(schoolString);
    String ritualString = "\\(ritual\\)";                                   //Finds if a spell is a ritual
    Pattern ritualPattern = Pattern.compile(ritualString);
    String descriptionString = "\nCasting Time: (.|\\n)+?(\\n\\n)";         //Finds the description of spells
    Pattern descriptionPattern = Pattern.compile(descriptionString);

    try
    {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Spell List.txt"));

        // buffer for storing file contents in memory
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");

        // for reading one line
        String line = null;

        // keep reading till readLine returns null
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            // keep appending last line read to buffer
            stringBuffer.append(line + "\n");
        }
        fullList = stringBuffer.toString();     //Convert stringBuffer to a normal String. Used for setting fullList = a substring

        boolean cont = true;
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) //This does not need to be set to 100. This is just a temporary number. Anything over 4 gives me this error, but under 4 I am fine. 
        {
            //Spell Title
            match = titlePattern.matcher(fullList);                             
            match.find();                                                       //Makes match point to the first title found
            finalTitle = match.group().substring(0, match.group().length()-1);  //finalTitle is set to found group, without the newline at the end
            allSpells.put(finalTitle, new Spell());                             //Creates unnamed Spell object tied to the matched title in the allSpells map
            spellArray.add(allSpells.get(finalTitle));                          //Adds the unnamed Spell object to a list. 
                                                                                //To be used for iterating through all Spells to find properties matching criteria


            //Spell Level
            match = levelPattern.matcher(fullList.substring(match.end(), match.end()+50));  //Gives an approximate region in which this could appear
            if(match.find())    //Accounts for cantrips. If no match for a level is found, it is set to 0
            {
                finalLevel = Integer.valueOf(match.group().substring(0, 1));
            }
            else
            {
                finalLevel = 0;
            }
            allSpells.get(finalTitle).setSpellLevel(finalLevel);


            //Spell School
            match = schoolPattern.matcher(fullList);
            match.find();
            finalSchool = Spell.School.valueOf(match.group().substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + match.group().substring(1, match.group().length())); //Capitalizes matched school
            allSpells.get(finalTitle).setSpellSchool(finalSchool);


            //Ritual?
            match = ritualPattern.matcher(fullList.substring(0, 75));
            if(match.find())
            {
                allSpells.get(finalTitle).setRitual(true);
            }
            else
                allSpells.get(finalTitle).setRitual(false);



            //Spell Description
            match = descriptionPattern.matcher(fullList);
            match.find();
            finalDescription = match.group().substring(1);      //Gets rid of the \n at the beginning of the description
            allSpells.get(finalTitle).setDescription(finalDescription);

            lastMatch = match.end();
            System.out.println(finalTitle);
            fullList = fullList.substring(lastMatch);
            
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

If it helps, I have the list I'm using [here](https://1drv.ms/t/s!As6RZqjpo3c3oj80768B2nqSeZ7Y).
As I mentioned in the comments of the code, going through the loop more than 4 times gives me this error, but under 4 does not. I have tried doing this as a while loop as well, and I get the same error.

I have tried searching for a solution online, but everything I see about this error just talks about recursive calls. If anyone has a solution for this I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks.

EDIT: The error list I'm getting is huge, so I put it in a text file [here](https://1drv.ms/t/s!As6RZqjpo3c3okDhlaSQ0dZm-sSZ)
. I know people are asking for stack traces, and I hope that this is what they mean. I'm still relatively new to java and have never had to work with stack traces before.

EDIT 2: I have found that if I simply replace the description regex with "\nCasting Time:" that it runs through the whole thing without errors. The only problem, of course, is that it doesn't collect all the information I want it to. Hopefully this information will help determine the problem though.

FINAL EDIT: I did a bit more searching once I found the specific line causing the problem, and found that increasing the stack size fixed the problem.

Comment: And what does the stack trace look like?

Comment: We need a stacktrace and the location in the code where the exception is thrown. Otherwise it's hard to tell what might cause the issue.

Comment: I added the error list I'm getting. If that wasn't what you were asking please let me know and I'll try to give the correct information.

Comment: Increasing the stack size is no solution.  Try this regex instead: `"(?ms)^Casting Time: (.+?)\n\n"`

Comment: @AlanMoore Your regex also worked, but would you mind explaining why I shouldn't increase the stack size? Additionally, could you please tell me what the (?ms)^ part of the regex does? I usually test my regex expressions at http://regexr.com/ but it doesn't recognize this format.

Answer (score 0):

By increasing the stack size, you're treating a symptom and leaving the problem unsolved.  In this case, the problem is an inefficient regex.

First, if you want to match anything *including newlines*, you should always use the DOTALL option.  An alternation like `.|\n` is much less efficient.  (It's also incorrect.  The dot matches anything that's not a [line terminator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#lt), which can be much more than just `\n`.)

Second, that alternation is inside a capturing group, with the quantifier outside the group: `(.|\n)+?`.  That means you're capturing one character at a time, only to overwrite the captured character with the next character, an so on.  You're making the regex engine do a lot of unnecessary work.

Here's the regex I would use:

```
"(?ms)^Casting Time: (.+?)\n\n"
```

The DOTALL option can be activated with the inline modifier, `(?s)`.  I also used the MULTILINE option, which lets me anchor the match to the beginning of the line with `^`.  That way, there's no need consume the leading `\n`, only to chop it off later.  In fact, if you use `group(1)` instead of `group()`, the trailing `\n\n` will be excluded as well.

As for RegExr, it uses a different regex flavor than Java's--one with far fewer features.  Most Java regexes will work on the excellent [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) site with the `pcre (php)` option selected.  For absolute compatibility, there RegexPlanet's [Java page](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html), or a code testing site like [Ideone](http://ideone.com/).